# Can I use jquery-ui button without flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-button

When I use [jquery-ui button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) to make an `<input type='checkbox'>` element behave like a button, I get a nice looking button, but it flickers when loading the page.

Before the `$("#checkbout").button()` runs, I see a normal, unstyled checkout, that turns into a styled button a few milliseconds afterwards.

What's the correct way to use Button without this flickering effect?

Comment: Are you calling `$("#checkbout").button()` inside `$(document).ready()` handler?

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much that you're using the button widget incorrectly--you're experiencing a FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content). This occurs when your page has lots of elements and JavaScript that runs when the page is ready. You can see the page unstyled for a few seconds because the page takes so long to load.

There are several strategies for avoiding this, but one simple one is to add styles for the button that hide it (using JavaScript) outside of `$(document).ready`, then remove the styles when the document is ready:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<style type='text/css'>.button { display: none; }</style>");
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /* Remove the class hiding the button and call the widget: */
            $(".button").removeClass("button").button();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/gdbB5/ (uses `setTimeout` to simulate a page loading)

You could also apply this technique to an entire content element that's experiencing the problem (like a `div` that contains most of your content that 's heavily modified by JavaScript).